# Configuration Manager

Tags: powershell

I'me new to powershell so don't bit me up :)
My question is this:
I have to setup two types of machine x86 and x64.
During this setup I have to check the version of .NET Framework install on the machine.
I'm doing it by invoking Test-Path:
Test-Key "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v1.1.4322" "Install"
what I'd like to do is this:
    # Check if the system is x64 architecture
    # in case of positive answere change the registry
    # to Wow6432Node
    if($os_architecture -eq "x64")
    {
        $dot_net_registry_root_path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node"
    }

```
# Add common framework path
$dot_net_registry_path = $dot_net_registry_root_path + "\NET Framework Setup\NDP\"

# Check 1.0 version of .NET Framework
$dot_net_1_0_registry_path = $dot_net_registry_root_path + "\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v1.0\SBSDisabled"

if(!(Test-Key $dot_net_1_0_registry_path "Install"))
{
    Write-Output ".NET Framework v1.0.3705 is NOT installed"
}
else
{
    Write-Output ".NET Framework v1.0.3705 is installed"
}

# Check 1.1 version of .NET Framework
$dot_net_1_1_registry_path = "'" + $dot_net_registry_path + "v1.1.4322"  + "'"

if (!(Test-Key $dot_net_1_1_registry_path "Install"))
{
    Write-Output "Please install .NET Framework v1.1.4322"
}
else
{
    Write-Output ".NET Framework v1.1.4322 is installed"
}
```

where Test-Key

```
function Test-Key([string]$path, [string]$key)
{
    if(!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $path)) { return $false }

    if ((Get-ItemProperty $path).$key -eq $null) { return $false }

    return $true
}
```

The problem is that when I'm using variable instead of quoted string Test-Path fail because of spaces into the path: "\NET Framework Setup"

What should do to fix this?

Comment: Please, can you give more precision, The code you give seems to work for me.

Comment: I modify the begining test ...

Answer (score 0):

I often end up putting "" around paths just to be certain, tried adding them to the `Test-Path` and `Get-ItemProperty` calls in the function above:

`if(!(Test-Path -LiteralPath "$path"))`

`if ((Get-ItemProperty "$path").$key`

You can get the architecture of a machine with the command

`(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture`